# How to run python script (and receive output) from java/spring-boot project which is inside a docker container?

Tags: java, python, docker, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am trying to migrate services on my Ubuntu 16.04 server to docker 18.09.2 (so that I can leverage kubernetes).  My problem is getting a Jar to work in Docker the way it works in my local machine and server.

Namely, I am trying to run a python script inside of my Java Spring Boot Application, capture the output of the Python, and then display the text. This works fine on my local machine , but when I build it on the docker base image and run it, nothing happens (i.e. null value is returned from Buffered Reader)

The base docker image is 'openkbs/jre-mvn-py3'. The 'HelloWorld.py' file is located in the SpringBoot project directory.

Taking from openkbs's documentation (https://hub.docker.com/r/openkbs/jre-mvn-py3/), I have tried a few different command's in my processString, but nothing is working. Commands like:

docker run -it --rm openkbs/jdk-mvn-py3 python3 -c 'print("Hello World")'

docker run -i --rm openkbs/jdk-mvn-py3 python3 < HelloWorld.py

Here are my relevant configurations and lines of code:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openkbs/jdk-mvn-py3
ADD target/dockerMaster.jar dockerMaster.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "dockerMaster.jar"]
```

Java:

```java
    @RequestMapping("/pytest")
    public String pytest() {
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String processString = "python3 HelloWorld.py";
        System.out.println(processString);

        try {
            Process extractProcess = rt.exec(processString);
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(extractProcess.getInputStream()));
            String pyString = input.readLine();
            return new String("<PYSTUFF>SUCCESS " + pyString + "</PYSTUFF>");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new String("<FAIL>PYTHON DID NOT RUN</FAIL>");
        } 
    }
```

Python:

```py
print("Hello World")
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with your run lines passing in Python code there?  Do you expect that to somehow place Python code where your Spring app will find it and run it?  I see nothing here to suggest that that would happen.  Your container is just running your Spring app, and then that app presumably is able to respond to a web request at the path `/pytest`.  I see that the Java code is trying to run a Python script named `HelloWorld.py`.  How do you expect that file to make it to where your Spring app is looking for it?  I see nothing here that will begin to do that.

Comment: Also, you seem to be running the `openkbs/jdk-mvn-py3` container image, not your own image created with your Dockerfile.  This image is just the starting point for your own container described by your Dockerfile.  You need to build an image from your Dockerfile, give it a name when you do so, and then use that name with `docker run`.  So none of your code even exists in the container you are running.

Comment: ...I just realized...you say you've tried things like `docker run -i --rm openkbs/jdk-mvn-py3 python3 < HelloWorld.py` "in your processString".  That string is in your Java, which it appears you are putting into a container.  So are you trying to run one container from inside another?  Please better explain what it is you want to do, and especially what those two `docker run` lines have to do with anything.

Comment: This Spring Boot project is a RestAPI which takes pdf files, parses them, and then returns a string based on the parsing algorithm. To that end, the end goal is to run pdfminer’s dumppdf.py (which I can already do both on local machine and on the server). For now, as a building block to transition to Docker, I am simply trying to make sure my container can run a simple python file and give me the output. The code as is runs on my local machine, on the server the same code runs with the location of the python files being more explicitly specified (as you suggest).

Comment: As for docker, I am building a new image from the Spring Boot project by running “docker build ...” in the project folder with a Dockerfile. I then run the image with “docker run ...”. It is this image I cannot get to run correctly. For clarity, I do not want to run a container in a container, simply to run one container which is a Sprong Boot Application which taps into python code at times.

Comment: Sounds reasonable.  Do you need to be able to pass in arbitrary Python via the REST API, or is it a single script that can be hard-coded into the container.  If so, then is @captainchhala's answer going in the right direction for you...is it basically that simple?

Comment: Whatever you do, Docker shouldn't impose any limitations other than learning curve.  I'm happy to help with that.  I just look at Docker containers like they're VMs, except that they're much easier to build and launch.

Comment: Ah.  Saw you gave the thumbs up to @captainchhala answer.  I hope you get it all working great soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not putting your HelloWorld.py file into the container that is why its not working what you need to do is add HelloWorld.py into the container and also make sure python is installed inside the container.

```
FROM openkbs/jdk-mvn-py3
ADD target/dockerMaster.jar dockerMaster.jar
ADD target/HelloWorld.py HelloWorld.py
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "dockerMaster.jar"]
```